# Average from two different dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have df like:

```
material plant  Order                
24990   89952   4568789,5098710     
24990   89952   9448609,1007081     
166621  3062    18364103            
166621  3062    78309139            
240758  3062    55146035            
276009  3062    38501581,857542
```

and df1 like:

```
material plant   Order      m1     m2      m3   m4   m5
24990     89952 4568789     0.123  0.214   0.0  0.0  0.0
24990     89952 5098710     1.000  0.363   0.0  0.0  0.0
24990     89952 9448609     0.0    0.345   0.0  1.0  0.0
24990     89952 1007081     0.0    0.756   0.0  1.0  0.0
166621    3062  18364103    0.0    0.0     0.0  0.0  0.0
166621    3062  78309139    0.0    1.0     0.0  0.0  0.0
240758    3062  55146035    1.0    1.0     1.0  0.0  0.0
276009    3062  38501581    1.0    1.0     1.0  0.0  0.0
276009    3062  38575428    1.0    1.0     1.0  0.0  0.0
```

I want to iterate through Order in df1 and when there is a match of Order in df2 then find average from m1 to m5.
I want to achieve df2 like:

```
material plant  Order              avg m1 avgm2 avgm3 avgm4 avgm5
24990   89952   4568789,5098710    0.5615 0.2885 0.0   0.0   0.0
24990   89952   9448609,1007081     
166621  3062    18364103            
166621  3062    78309139            
240758  3062    55146035            
276009  3062    38501581,857542
```

I am trying different ways to achieve df2 such as:

```
df2 = (df.groupby(df1, sort=False)['Order'].apply(lambda x: ','.split(x.astype(str)))
   .mean() 
   .reset_index()
.reindex(columns=df.columns))
 print (df2)
```

second:

```
group = df.columns[np.r_[0:3, 3:len(df.columns)]]
 res = df1.groupby(group)['Order'].apply(list).mean().reset_index()
```

But I am not sure if this is the correct way to get it.

Comment: Why not merge two DF on material and plant and then apply your requirement.

Comment: let me try to merge on material and plant

Comment: @Rocky - What is expected output of last line of `DataFrame` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = (df1.join(df1.set_index(['material','plant'], append=True)['Order']
          .str.split(',', expand=True)
          .stack()
          .astype(int)
          .reset_index(name='Order')
          .merge(df2, on=['material','plant','Order'], how='left') 
          .drop(['material','plant','Order','level_3'], axis=1)
          .groupby('level_0')
          .mean())
          )
print (df)
   material  plant            Order      m1      m2   m3   m4   m5
0     24990  89952  4568789,5098710  0.5615  0.2885  0.0  0.0  0.0
1     24990  89952  9448609,1007081  0.0000  0.5505  0.0  1.0  0.0
2    166621   3062         18364103  0.0000  0.0000  0.0  0.0  0.0
3    166621   3062         78309139  0.0000  1.0000  0.0  0.0  0.0
4    240758   3062         55146035  1.0000  1.0000  1.0  0.0  0.0
5    276009   3062  38501581,857542  1.0000  1.0000  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

**Explanation**:

1. First create `DataFrame` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
2. Join to second `DataFrame` with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and left join
3. Remove unnecessary columns with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
4. Then aggregate `mean`
5. Output Series is [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)ed to first `DataFrame`

**Detail**:

```
df3 = (df1.set_index(['material','plant'], append=True)['Order']
          .str.split(',', expand=True)
          .stack()
          .astype(int)
          .reset_index(name='Order')
          .merge(df2, on=['material','plant','Order'], how='left'))
print (df3)
   level_0  material  plant  level_3     Order     m1     m2   m3   m4   m5
0        0     24990  89952        0   4568789  0.123  0.214  0.0  0.0  0.0
1        0     24990  89952        1   5098710  1.000  0.363  0.0  0.0  0.0
2        1     24990  89952        0   9448609  0.000  0.345  0.0  1.0  0.0
3        1     24990  89952        1   1007081  0.000  0.756  0.0  1.0  0.0
4        2    166621   3062        0  18364103  0.000  0.000  0.0  0.0  0.0
5        3    166621   3062        0  78309139  0.000  1.000  0.0  0.0  0.0
6        4    240758   3062        0  55146035  1.000  1.000  1.0  0.0  0.0
7        5    276009   3062        0  38501581  1.000  1.000  1.0  0.0  0.0
8        5    276009   3062        1    857542    NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: To note, if an order is missing from `df1` (857542), this method assumes it is has the same values as the other non-missing order.

Comment: @jezrael, as in your example it is  like: 166621   3062         18364103  0.0000  0.0000  0.0  0.0  0.0 
for me it is printing nan nan nan nan nan for m1 to m5

Comment: Maybe problem is with types of columns, maybe help if remove `.astype(int)` if both columns `Order` are strings.

Comment: it did not work like that but I had to use some other tricks.

Comment: @Rocky, please share your solution with the community. You can post an answer yourself, even accept it if there is a significant difference to the others. This helps other users.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way via `numpy` and a mapping dictionary.

```
# map Order to values with a dictionary
mapper = dict(zip(df1['Order'], df1[['m'+str(i) for i in range(1, 6)]].values))

# map comma-separated numbers to list of integers
df2_orders = [list(map(int, i)) for i in df2['Order'].str.split(',')]

# calculate mean
res = [np.mean([mapper.get(o, [0]*5) for o in order], axis=0).tolist() \
       for order in df2_orders]

# join results to dataframe
df2 = df2.join(pd.DataFrame(res, columns=['avg_m'+str(i) for i in range(1, 6)]))
```

Note if data is missing (for example, order `857542`), you can specify what values to include, here I use 0s.

**Result**

```
   material  plant            Order  avg_m1  avg_m2  avg_m3  avg_m4  avg_m5
0     24990  89952  4568789,5098710  0.5615  0.2885     0.0     0.0     0.0
1     24990  89952  9448609,1007081  0.0000  0.5505     0.0     1.0     0.0
2    166621   3062         18364103  0.0000  0.0000     0.0     0.0     0.0
3    166621   3062         78309139  0.0000  1.0000     0.0     0.0     0.0
4    240758   3062         55146035  1.0000  1.0000     1.0     0.0     0.0
5    276009   3062  38501581,857542  0.5000  0.5000     0.5     0.0     0.0
```